# What shall i do if i receave this message "have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?"

Tags: java, android, kotlin, variables

im developing a project to finish my school but im learnig android from the ground and its being hard.
Im trying to put togeter 2 diferent projects. The first one which is an tic tac toe game it's openning when I click the options menu item that was declared to it but my second game its not oppening and it crashes and an error appers: "Have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?"

I tryied several things but nothing works . I think it may be a leak of the OnOptionsItemSelected of the item that corresponds in the options menu, but i dont know how to solve it, someone to help it?
Sry for possible errors xD
[my manifest xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BeRwH.png)

Comment: Read https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/intro-activities#da and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and explain what "several things" you tried so we don't waste time telling you to try things you already did.

Comment: I tried to put onclick methods that i have on it, tried to change id's , create methods things that were usefull... In that first website you sent to me it says to open the manifest ... ill read it

Comment: Hey @dominicoder, i've read it, and i've done some changes but now, i've got a new problem . my app consists in a menu who have an Options Menu that may go to 3 diferent games only one is working but now that i have added this                                                   
           <activity
            android:name=".Jogo_pedra_papel_tesoura"
            android:exported="true">   my menu dont appears, just shows the activity that i´ve put. my manifestxml is up there tell me something pls tnx

Comment: Forget it i've already discover it! It has to be whit where i place it it must be over the mainactivity! tnx very much !!

Answer (score 1):

Can you paste the code of your AndroidManifest.xml file?

I believe you forgot to mention your Activity there.
If it's one single Activity, you need to make sure you'll have it with an intent-filter on it.

If it's another activity, you just need to declare it in your Manifest file without the intent-filter block on it.

You must declare all of your activities in your Manifest file.
e.g

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <application
        ...>

        <activity
            android:name="name of your main activity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="name of your second activity">

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Edit:
I just saw you attached a screenshot of your Manifest file.
What is the name of the activity you are trying to open when click on the menu item?